# No value returned after converting code into a function

Tags: python, function

I wrote this code and then used that code to create a function. I changed print to return but nothing happens.

```
contints = ["Europe", "North_America", "South_America", "Asia", "Australia", "Africa"]
Europe = "rich life"
North_America = "average life"
South_America = "poor life"
Asia = "average life"
Australia = "rich life"
Africa = "very poor life"
print(random.choice(contints))
if random.choice(contints) == "Europe":
    print("You will have a " + Europe)
elif random.choice(contints) == "North_America":
    print("You will have a " + North_America)
elif random.choice(contints) == "South_America":
    print("You will have a " + South_America)
elif random.choice(contints) == "Asia":
    print("You will have a " + Asia)
elif random.choice(contints) == "Australia":
    print("You will have a " + Australia)
else:
    print("You will have a " + Africa)
```

This works but when I make a function out of it and change to return statements nothings happens while I want to return the answer. I want that the continent is randomly chosen and then return the output.

```
import random
def continent(contints):
    contints = ["Europe", "North_America", "South_America", "Asia", "Australia", "Africa"]
    Europe = "rich life"
    North_America = "average life"
    South_America = "poor life"
    Asia = "average life"
    Australia = "rich life"
    Africa = "very poor life"
    if random.choice(contints) == "Europe":
        return Europe
    elif random.choice(contints) == "North_America":
        return North_America
    elif random.choice(contints) == "South_America":
        return South_America
    elif random.choice(contints) == "Asia":
        return Asia
    elif random.choice(contints) == "Australia":
        return Australia
    else:
        return Africa
```

Answer (score 0):

You have juste declare your function, which is fine. Then, you need to call it with lines like

```py
response = continents()
print(response)
```

by the  way, I think your function is not clearly declared. You should remove the argument `contints`.

Comment: Thanks you so much! It works fine with the adjustments you gave as feedback